# CartoDB Torque - using a start and end for each point

Tags: cartodb

I am trying to make an animated map using the torque from CartoDB.
I have about 8000 points, which I would like to show and hide following a 'period of validity'. Let's say for instance it shows data for one day; some points will be valid all day, others from midnight to 6am, others 4am to 8am, and so on and so forth. The torque would start at midnight, showing all the points valid at that time, then to 1am, removing and adding some, and so on until midnight.

In order to do that, I would like to set a start and an end time, but I cannot find any option for this. I saw the cumulative option, but then it would stay until the end of the animation, which is not exactly what I want.
Any suggestion would be welcomed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing it cames to me is repeating the records as many times as the time step you want on the animated map and assigning this new time as the torque animation field.

So if your torque steps every hour, and your point is valid for six, then you'll have one point per hour. To produce that query you'll probably need to use `generate_series`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of that too... but I wasn't aware of 'generate_series', do you have a link for documentation?
I'm worried it would become quite heavy though, with so many points.

Comment: Sure, [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) docs.

I don't have any example at hand for this specific use case, sorry.

Regarding query size torque json files are cached but you probably want to create a new dataset from that query to get the fastest result.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look that way :)